# Visual studio not serving angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm

I just cloned my angular app that i have been working on my other machine into a new machine. When I click the run with debugging button in visual studio, it just lunched a web browser page to the configured localhost port but i wont open a separate command line and execute `ng serve` or `npm start`. instead it just runs a ng build inside visual studio's build output.

- every thing was working on the other machine correctly.
- noded js is installed and angular cli is also installed
- app does launch correctly when i execute `ng serve` or `npm start` in a command line manually.

here is my `.esproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.74-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupCommand>npm start</StartupCommand>
    <JavaScriptTestFramework>Jasmine</JavaScriptTestFramework>
    <!-- Command to run on project build -->
    <BuildCommand>
    </BuildCommand>
    <!-- Command to create an optimized build of the project that's ready for publishing -->
    <ProductionBuildCommand>npm run build</ProductionBuildCommand>
    <!-- Folder where production build objects will be placed -->
    <BuildOutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist\A16Net.Presentation.Client</BuildOutputFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
...

</Project>
```

I tried :

- creating a new angular template in visual studio and test running that one in visual studio and it worked just fine. the `.esproj` files seemed simmilar.
- modifing the build command like so

```
<BuildCommand>ng serve
</BuildCommand>
```

it just executed the command in visual studio's build output section , but got stuck.

- checking the `.vscode` folder contents, `packages.json`, `angular.json`. All files were the same compared to the new angular template.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a visual studio v17.8 bug. duplicate of question [angular non-js module files depricated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482519/angular-v-17-0-0-application-cannot-run-crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-depr/77488596#77488596).

Comment: [microsoft developer community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/esproj-will-not-launch-StartupCommand-i/10516578?sort=newest)