# Angular v.17.0.0 Application cannot run (crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated)

Tags: angular, rendering

I am moving from angular v.16 to v.17. I created a simple workspace monorepo app, and once I run "ng serve appName" the browser is showing this error in console.

crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

I know this issue was posted before, but none of that works, including having "No throttling" in Browse's Network setting. Is there a difference way how we should start angular applications?

I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Angular CLI: 17.0.0
Node: 20.9.0
Package Manager: npm 10.1.0

[image]

Comment: The warning is not related to your issue. Are you using SSR ?

Comment: No, when I created the application, I chose "NO" for SSR.

Comment: The angular application cannot run on port 4200. It can run in other ports though. I have no idea why this happened suddenly.

Answer (score -1):

This issue happened to me when I updated Visual studio from `17.7` to `17.8`. For some reason visual studio does not run `npm start`. Usually a console should open and run `npm start` or `ng serve` but it does not.

I am using `angular 16` and `node 18`.

I Also tried syncing .esproj and packages.json files and literally any other config file with a newly made angular template (which works just as expected). but that did not work neither.

Comment: For me, I think something now is not letting the apps running in port 4200. If I tried another port like 51551, the app runs fine.  It seems related to a firewall in my machine I guess, because I tried in Edge also and same issue. Then, I created a simple angular app in another machine, and it works fine.

Comment: It seems like a visual studio bug to me. because if i create a new angular template on the same machine with the new visual studio it works fine. on the default port :4200.

Comment: I am not running from VS, but just using cmd terminal. I went back to angular v16, and all works fine. It is when I create angular app using v17 and node (v18 or v20) when this issue happens. As I said, this issue just happens in a particular machine, regardless the browser I use.

Comment: I started getting this after upgrading VS from 17.7 to 17.8 as well.  I filed this report with MS: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Existing-ESPROJ-no-longer-launches-a-win/10518278?scope=follow&sort=newest&ref=native&refTime=1700233822700&refUserId=ca713e96-af0d-4bd4-988f-db61af348e1f

Comment: I added a comment to your report. Seems like the problem happens when the angular project is inside a solution folder . You can bring the project to the root of your solution in the solution explorer as a workaround.

Comment: This is about some completely different issue than what the question here asks. 1. The question does not mention VS 2. The question clearly states that `ng serve` was ran. So an answer saying it's a VS bug where `ng serve` didn't run does not relate at all to the situation.